# Voice in TTS Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, localization, text-to-speech

Does anyone know where I can find a list of all the different available languages for Text to speech? e.g. en_GB, en_US e.t.c.?

Also will offering different languages for text to speech require an internet connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method [speechVoices](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avspeechsynthesisvoice/1619697-speechvoices) in the class AVSpeechSynthesisVoice returns all the currently available voices on the current device.

Devices ship with at least one, often two (one male, one female) high quality voices for the current locale's language (e.g. a US iPhone will have a high quality male en_US voice and a high quality female en_US voice). They also ship with a larger number of lower quality alternate dialect and international voices (e.g. on that US iPhone, en_GB will be present but lower quality - on a GB iPhone it would be the other way around).

Users can choose to [download additional high quality voices](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202362), but otherwise an internet connection is not required for TTS.